# How to change compile only one class of a java source code

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI library on Java. I want to add a method to XWPFSDTContent class. I have the source code but when I want to compiling after adding method I have to use "ant jar" command but it takes so much time and makes it harder to debug because it compiles the whole library. Is there a way to compile only one source file? I can't use javac command because of its dependency on the library.

Comment: POI has a gradle build file too. This will do a better job of handling the need to only recompile 1 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the source code of `Apache POI` imported into a java project in some kind of IDE. Then you basically only need to edit your one class, afterwards the IDE should have generated the new `.class` file.

Take this class file (and any possibly existing anonymous inner class files) and copy it into your `jar` (replacing the old `.class` files). That should work assuming that you compiled the class file with the same java version as the rest of the classes inside the `jar` and your `jar` is not signed.

Comment: I imported them as .class files in jar to my Eclipse IDE workspace. I have the source code seperately. So I have to add source codes of library to project but it cause problem because of package dependencies. Is there a way to add folder as package to Eclipse?

Comment: You should probably use some build tool like `maven` to import the dependencies. If you check the maven repo [`here`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/4.1.0) you should be able to obtain a pom listing all required dependencies and their version.